# travis build docker image with git ssh

Tags: git, docker, npm, travis-ci

I am trying to rollout one of my build using travis.  As part of the pre script I am building a docker image.  Within the docker image, I need to get a package from my git repository.  git is trying to do ssh and I am trying to get it to use https.  Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Docker file

```
FROM node:15-alpine as builder
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
RUN git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
```

travis.yml

```
sudo: required

language: node_js
node_js:
  - '14'

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "nightly" ]; then docker build -t something/clientv1 -f ./app/Dockerfile.nightly ./app; fi
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "staging" ]; then docker build -t something/clientv1 -f ./app/Dockerfile.staging ./app; fi
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "beta" ]; then docker build -t something/clientv1 -f ./app/Dockerfile.beta ./app; fi
  - docker build -t something/nginx ./nginx
  - docker build -t something/api ./server

script:
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "nightly" ] || [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "staging"] || [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "beta" ]; docker push something/clientv1; fi
  - docker push something/nginx
  - docker push something/api

deploy:
...
```

package.json

```
...      
"dependencies": {
         "react-awesome-query-builder": "https://github.com/billtlee/react-awesome-query-builder.git#forLocal"
      }
...
```

travis output

```
npm notice 
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command git ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/[secure]/react-awesome-query-builder.git
npm ERR! error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
npm ERR! fatal: unable to fork
```

Answer (score 0):

An URL of a dependency starts with `ssh://` and you haven't added a rule to rewrite such URLs. Add one:

```
RUN git config --global url."https://".insteadOf ssh://git@
```

Comment: @Bill I changed the answer a bit — added `git@` to the end of the URL (to remove it from the rewritten URLs), please try.

Comment: unfortunately it's still not working. thx!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by downgrading to 14-alpine from 15-alpine.  I don't know what changed.  But no matter what I did, it kept wanting to use ssh...